# Recurringly calling a RIA service with Azure Scheduler

Tags: azure-scheduler

I currently have a `WorkerRole` doing that for me.
Basically, it keeps sleeping and wakes up every hour to call the service.

But with the recent release (in my country) of Azure Scheduler, I'm wondering if I can replace that non-free WorkerRole with a free Sheduler job.

So I tried creating a job with a PUT request like this one:
http://.azurewebsites.net/ClientBin/.svc/binary/

But I get the following error in the scheduler history:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

Is it a URL problem?
Is it an authentication issue?
Is it even feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody has any idea? Am I on the completely wrong track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used a WebJob to do my recurring task.